# Liferay: perform an action when a -LocalServiceUtil is available

Tags: liferay, liferay-service-builder

I have implemented a functional Liferay service using service builder and I want to call a method on the `-LocalServiceUtil` class just as soon as I possibly can. This is a task I wish to perform when the service starts and also when the service is redeployed.

Even though all the methods on the `-LocalServiceUtil` class are static, they will throw a `BeanLocatorException` if they are called too soon.

> com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.BeanLocatorException: BeanLocator has not been set for servlet context portal-navigation-impl

Is there any way to call a method on the `-LocalServiceImpl` instance or otherwise so that I can do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you speak about the initialization order: I'm not 100% sure about this, but I'd write a [startup action](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/performing-a-custom-action-using-a-hook). This gets run everytime a hook (or plugin) starts up - including a redeploy. Sounds like what you want - and if the initialization order works, this is your solution.

Otherwise: Create a separate hook that's dependent on the one that you're currently using. That will be restarted as well, but only run once the hook providing the *-LocalService did already start up. (dependency is declared in `liferay-plugin-package.properties`, with the key `required-deployment-context` - this is from memory - somebody correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: That is some good information, thanks for responding. I tried out the startup action, which is helpful - it fires when I start up Liferay, but it does not fire when I hot-deploy my WAR.

Comment: It doesn't? I'd expect it to. It can only fire once the hook is deployed, and I always expected it to fire every time the hook deploys. Not to say that this is guaranteed - unfortunately I can't check this right now

Comment: After viewing your comment above I went back and rechecked.  It seems that when I am running using JRebel it does not get called when I hot deploy (a real hot-deploy, not just a JRebel class reload).  But when I disable the JRebel agent, the startup action listener gets called when I hot deploy. I do not know why that would be...

Comment: ok - JRebel in the game and everything might change. Good to know that my memory isn't too bad :) Thanks for reporting back