# How do I use webjars in a Liferay portlet

Tags: liferay-6, webjars

I have been trying to include [shufflejs](https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/) in a Liferay (6.2) portlet.

1. I have added the following dependency to my `pom.xml` file:

   ```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
     <artifactId>shufflejs</artifactId>
     <version>4.0.0</version>
     <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. I have confirmed that on my tomcat server, the `webapps/my-portlet/WEB-INF/lib/shufflejs-4.0.0.jar` is present and contains, within it, the `META-INF/resources/webjars/shufflejs/4.0.0/dist/shuffle.js`
3. I have included the following line in my `liferay-portlet.xml` file:

   ```
   <header-portlet-javascript>
     /webjars/shufflejs/4.0.0/dist/shuffle.js
   </header-portlet-javascript>
   ```
4. When I load my portlet's page with my browser, I get everything except I get a '404 Not Found' error for `http://localhost:20080/my-portlet/webjars/shufflejs/4.0.0/dist/shuffle.js?browserId=other&minifierType=js&languageId=en_US&b=6210&t=1465296591338`

What am I missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of my troubles. I have deployed my portlet and run the portal in Eclipse with JRebel. When I deploy/run my portlet standalone without JRebel, this resource is found. Moreover, I am able to then bring the portal down and then bring it back up in Eclipse/JRebel - now the resource can be found.

I have encountered similar problems when running with Eclipse/JRebel before (see [Liferay: perform an action when a -LocalServiceUtil is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684810/liferay-perform-an-action-when-a-localserviceutil-is-available)). All in all Eclipse/JRebel is great, but sometimes a little wonkiness occurs when deploying portlets.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a Servlet 3.0 container, you have the wrong URL.  You need to use:

```
<header-portlet-javascript>
  /webjars/shufflejs/4.0.0/dist/shuffle.js
</header-portlet-javascript>
```

According to the [webjars documentation](http://www.webjars.org/documentation#servlet3):

> **Instructions for Servlet 3**
>
> With any Servlet 3 compatible container,
>   the WebJars that are in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory are automatically
>   made available as static resources. This works because anything in a
>   `META-INF/resources` directory in a JAR in `WEB-INF/lib` is automatically
>   exposed as a static resource.

*Note, this documentation would indicate that you should be using `webjars/shufflejs/4.0.0/dist/shuffle.js`, but a little experimentation with the Liferay `<header-portlet-javascript>` config leads to the necessity of the preceding `/` as Liferay will concatenate this URL onto the end of the portlet name to form the full Liferay resource URL.*

Comment: I tried this before, and to make sure, I tried it again and it did not work. First of all the `liferay-portlet.xml` likes it's documents sourced from the `webapp` root directory and for other items (`webapp/resources/css/*` and `webapp/resources/js/*` must be referenced starting with `/resource/...`)

Comment: This comment is simply not true...  Liferay does not require any sort of folder structure inside of your webapp.  Perhaps you are confusing this with the JSF convention for `/resources`?  Also, webjars uses the servlet 3.0 feature in that any jar in its lib folder will expose all resources contained in its `META-INF/resources` directory.

Comment: Your information above is correct, yet it did not solve my problem - since my problem persisted even when following your information above. I have updated my question and have answered it below with information about the root cause of my problem.